# JQuery: how to get the name of input checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I have many input checkbox in my html page.
Each checkbox input is 'linked' to an input text.

I try to code a function to look for checked checkbox and when checked it should set the 'linked' text NULL (and when checked back it should get the initial value).

So I need to loop on different checkbox input to get name, value, etc...

Below, started code...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var chkbox = '';
    const obj = {
        bra_00A_act: 1,
        bra_00A_lib: 'Polyvitamines et oligo-éléments',
        bra_00B_act: 0,
        bra_00B_lib: 'Polyvitamines et oligo-éléments',
        bra_00C_act: 1,
        bra_00C_lib: 'Hydroxychloroquine'
    };
    $.each(obj, function(index, val) 
    {
        if(index.substr(8,3) == 'act'){
            if(val == 1){
                chkbox +='<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" class="checkbox" id="'+index+'" name="'+index+'" value="'+val+'">'
            } else {
                chkbox +='<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="'+index+'" name="'+index+'" value="'+val+'">'
            }           
        } else {
            chkbox +='<span>'+val.substr(0,4)+'... '+'</span>'
        }

    });

    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
      if(this.checked) {
        // allow user to enter data in the linked input text
      }else if(!this.checked) {
        // set the 'linked' input text with NULL 
        // value should be registered to be recovered if user checked again
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

pass "this" in jQuery selector (something like this $(this)) and try access to needed attribute with "attr" method(function)

also 'checked' attribute in HTML is boolean you must pass true or false